# How to handle separate layouts of different namespaces in compoundjs

Tags: node.js, compoundjs

Hey guys i am a noob who has just started working on nodejs . I am developing a web application on nodejs using compoundjs.

This is the structure of my view folder

```
views/
|-- admin
|   |-- games
|   |-- squadplayertypes
|   `-- toursection
|       |-- tourformats
|       |-- tourmatchtypes
|       `-- tours
|-- layouts
|   |-- admin
|   |   `-- toursection
```

I have created a name space to handle all requests that are directed to "/admin".

Now I want to know if there is away where I can define a common layout for all the routes inside the namespace "admin".

This is how i have written my routes.js

```
    admin.namespace('toursection', function(toursection){
        toursection.resources('tours',function(tour){
            tour.post('fetchTourDetails','tours#fetchTourDetails',{collection:true});
        });
        toursection.resources('tourmatchtypes');
        toursection.resources('tourformats');
    });
    /*Routes for squad players and all related dependancies*/
    admin.resources('squadplayers');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is *currently* a way to do this (at least neatly in the namespace area). Layouts are searched in the [controller-extensions library](https://github.com/1602/compound/blob/master/lib/controller-extensions.js#L230), where the controller's name is used to search for a layout, then it defaults on the application layout.

However, it is possible to define one layout to be used between several views. You can use the `layout` function at the top of a controller to change the layout. For example, I can define the layout `app/views/layouts/reports_layout.ejs` for the reports namespace.

Example namespace:

```
map.namespace('reports', function (reports) {
    reports.resources('billing');
});
```

Controller:

```
layout('reports');

action('index', function () {
    this.title = 'Billing Report';
    render();
});
```

Comment: Thank you @making3 . A very clean way of doing what I was trying to achieve .

Answer (score 1):

Well I believe @making3 has pointed out a standard way to do it. Although there can be a dirty hack that can be done in the application controller if you are sure that the url belonging to your admin section will always have **/admin/** in it and such urls will only load the admin layout you can follow the following method and add the below code to your application controller

```
before('mylayout', function(){
    if(req._parsedUrl.pathname.indexOf('/admin/') != -1)
        layout('admin/admin');
    next();
});
```

This adds a before handler which checks the current url without the query params and if it contains **/admin/** it will set the layout for all the controller actions called with admin namespace routes.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Correctly as pointed by @guruwinder this will fail if you have configured the routes to accept a param in **:param**  fashion. So please be careful before using this.

Comment: This solution will work for most cases but if I have defined a route as  _/signin/:param/_  and in place of param i send **admin** then your solution fails.

Comment: I agree that you can do this. If you're going this far with it, I would suggest implementing a flexible way into the controller library, that could look up a layout based on the parent path. `/admins/toursection` would attempt to find the admins_layout for example.